# How get \Diamond and \square with TeX Gyre Termes (or Pagella)?

Tags: unicode-math, tex-gyre-math

How do I produce the equivalent of the symbols `\square` and `\Diamond` from `amsfonts` if I'm using TeX Gyre Termes or TeX Gyre Pagella?

For example, XeLaTeXing the following gives `Undefined control sequence` at `\square` (and similarly for `\Diamond` if the line with `\square` is commented out).

From http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf, I am aware of the unicode-math symbols `\enclosequare` and `\enclosediamond`, but the former is larger than the amsfonts `\square` and the latter is just a rotated square rather than the slimmer amsfonts `\Diamond`; also, the ams symbols have leading space that the corresponding unicode-math symbols do not. (To see the differences, uncomment the line `% \RequirePackage{amsfonts}`.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Termes}
\RequirePackage{unicode-math}
% Need amsmath first to avoid conflict for \dddot, etc.
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
% Won't following overwrite def's of TeX Gyre Math symbols?
% \RequirePackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}

$x=2$\\
$\enclosesquare$\\
$\enclosediamond$\\
$\square$\\
$\Diamond$

\end{document}
```

**Purpose:**
I want these symbols to use strictly for end-of-proof and, analogously, end-of-example. I've added a proposed answer giving my solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Load `amssymb` in advance of `unicode-math`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}

\begin{document}

$x=2 + \square + \Diamond$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, use symbols available in the font:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}

\newcommand{\square}{□}    % U+25A1
\renewcommand{\Diamond}{◊} % U+25CA

\begin{document}

$x=2 + \square + \Diamond$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does including `\RequirePackage{amssymb}` change any symbols given by `\RequirePackage{unicode-math}` (or vice versa)?

Comment: @murray I believe that `unicode-math` will override the possible conflicts. The square is actually available in TeX Gyre Termes Math, but not the diamond. You can try to import them from other fonts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the unicode characters directly, i.e., ♢ and □ (code points U+2662 and U+25A1), by typing them in your document or by defining a `\newcommand` (for using the symbols in isolation) or `\DeclareMathOperator` (for using them as, well, math operators). See for example http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tg-math/gust_e-foundry-math_fonts-presentation.pdf for the symbols that are available in this font. You can also use the original `amssymb` commands together with TeX Gyre Termes Math. Note that `\enclosesquare` and `\enclosediamond` are combining characters, intended to enclose the previous character in a square or diamond.

Some examples:

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Termes}
\RequirePackage{unicode-math}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{amsfonts}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}

\newcommand\mydiamondsingle{♢}
\newcommand\mysquaresingle{□}
\DeclareMathOperator{\mydiamond}{♢}
\DeclareMathOperator{\mysquare}{□}

\begin{document}

$x=2$\\
$♢,\mydiamond,\Diamond,\quad x\enclosediamond$\\
$□,\mysquare,\square,\quad y\enclosesquare$\\

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Does including `\RequirePackage{amsfonts}` change any symbols given by `\RequirePackage{unicode-math}` (or vice versa)?

Comment: How did you type those actual diamond and square symbols in your code?

Comment: I copied them from https://unicode-search.net/unicode-namesearch.pl?term=DIAMOND and https://unicode-search.net/unicode-namesearch.pl?term=SQUARE.

Comment: I hadn't reallized, now that UTF-8 is the default input encoding, one could copy characters like that into `.tex` source. Very useful!

Answer (score 1):

The `amsmath` `\Diamond` and `\square` look more like `\mdlgwhtlozenge` and `\mdlgwhtsquare`, respectively.  however, TeX Gyre Pagella Math does not contain `\mdlgwhtsquare` (as of version 1.632).

If a Unicode math font is missing a particular glyph, or you just don’t like how it looks, you can patch in the symbol from another font with the `range=` option of `\setmathfont`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}[Ligatures=Common, Scale=1.0]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\setmathfont[Scale=MatchUppercase,
             range={\mdlgwhtlozenge, \mdlgwhtsquare}
            ]{STIX Two Math}

\begin{document}

amssymb: \( x \Diamond y \square \)

Pagella with STIX Two: \( x \mdlgwhtlozenge y \mdlgwhtsquare \)
\end{document}
```

[image: Font samples]

As of July 2019, `range=` doesn’t work together with `version=`.  This mainly causes problems if you use bold math.

Comment: I do use bold math, but just for particular letters and symbols. How does `version=` relate to bold math?

Comment: @murray `unicode-math` implements `\boldmath` and `\boldsymbol` by loading `\setmathfont[version=bold]`. This happens automatically if you load a math font that has a bold version. I think your use case should still work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my proposed solution based upon https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/501596/13492, but with some manipulation of the glyphs for the square and diamond so as to make their appearance as end-of-proof and end-of-example, respectively, when using XeLaTeX very close to their appearance when using pdfLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm} % load now to avoid openbox clash

\usepackage{iftex}
\ifTUTeX
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX }
  \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}[Scale=1.0]
  \setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
   \newcommand\myDiamond{♢}
   \newcommand\mySquare{\raisebox{0.75pt}{\scalebox{0.93}{$□$}}}
   \mathchardef\timessymbol=\numexpr\times-"2000\relax
\else
  \RequirePackage[theoremfont]{newtxtext}
  \RequirePackage{newtxmath}%
  \DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbfsf}{\encodingdefault}{\sfdefault}{bx}{n}
  \newcommand{\mySquare}{\square}
  \newcommand{\myDiamond}{\Diamond}
\fi

\renewcommand{\qed}{\quad\hbox{\qedsymbol}}% run-in QED
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\mySquare$}

\usepackage{thmtools}
%
\declaretheoremstyle[bodyfont=\mdseries\slshape]{thmstyle}
\declaretheorem[style=thmstyle,name=Theorem,numberwithin=section]{theorem}
%
\declaretheoremstyle[bodyfont=\normalfont]{exstyle}
\declaretheorem[
  style=exstyle,numberlike=theorem,
  preheadhook=\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\myDiamond$}\pushQED{\qed},
  postfoothook=\popQED
  ]
{example}

\begin{document}
\section{Triangles}

\begin{theorem}
The square on the hypotenuse equals the sum of the squares on the other two sides.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
Consider the following diagram\dots .
Thus
\[ a^{2} + b^{2} = c^{2}\qedhere\]
\end{proof}

\begin{example}
As a particular case, 
\[
3^{2} + 4^{2} = 5^{2}= c^{2 }\qedhere
\]
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

Output from pdfLaTeX:

[image: end-of-proof and end-of-example, pdfLaTeX]

Output from XeLaTeX:

[image: end-of-proof and end-of-example, XeLaTeX]